# How can I display a List<String>?

Tags: arrays, string, jakarta-ee, controller

I have a List and I want to print this list via system.out.println()

My query in my repository is like this :"

```
@Query("select groupe, AVG(tauxCharge) from EquilibrageFrequentiel E where 
tauxCharge is not null and tauxCharge != '0'"
        + " and base=:base group by groupe")
public List<String> tauxDeChargeParLigne(@Param("base")Long base);"
```

And in my controller, I try to display each element in the list group by groupe

```
List<String> tauxDeChargeAssemblage1 = EquilibrageFrequentielService.tauxDeChargeAssemlage(base1);
    for (String tauxDeChargeAssemblage : tauxDeChargeAssemblage1)
    {
        System.out.println(tauxDeChargeAssemblage);
    }
```

I got these error: "java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String"
What can I do to display my list? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your query returns two values per row. Why are you expecting this to be one String?

Comment: When I sent the list to my html, I can easyli display it by using "<tr th:each="LIST : ${tauxDeChargeAssemblage1}">
 <td  th:text="${LIST[0]}" ></td>
 <td  th:text="${LIST[1]}" ></td>" that's why i was expected to be one String ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **projection**. So convenient way is to create a DTO describing data your query returns (tuples of `String`(?), `Integer/Long`):

```
@Query("select new org.example.MyDTO(groupe, AVG(tauxCharge))"
    + " from EquilibrageFrequentiel E"
    + " where tauxCharge is not null and tauxCharge != '0'"
    + " and base=:base group by groupe")
public List<MyDTO> tauxDeChargeParLigne(@Param("base")Long base);
```

where DTO is like:

```
package org.example;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class MyDTO {
    private String groupe; // or whatever is ther data type of your groupe
    private Long average;
}
```

Or maybe you just want a list of `groupe`s (assuming it is a string), in that case just drop the AVG part, like:

```
@Query("select groupe
    + " from EquilibrageFrequentiel"
    + " E where tauxCharge is not null and tauxCharge != '0'"
    + " and base=:base group by groupe")
public List<String> tauxDeChargeParLigne(@Param("base")Long base);"
```

Comment: So I have to create an entire class(model) for on query ? Is that the only way to display a List<String> ?

Comment: Yes, because as I said above in comment, your query doesn't return a String, but a pair of objects: String and Integer or Long. That's why you wrap it.

Comment: @LucThilliez Not necessarily. But if you want to show list of string you have to select a string. Now you select a tuple of two values and it is unclear what is the string you want. This is how to handle that tuple.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right AVG(tauxCharge) isn't a String, it's all my bad !